# In Primefaces inputText required=true, how can I remove ui-state-error as soon as something is entered?

Tags: java, jquery, css, jsf, primefaces

When submitting a form that includes a required inputText, the styles that indicate not validated fields remain in place until submitting again. I want the styles to disappear as soon as the field is edited.

```
<p:inputText value="#{data.bezeichnung}" 
             id="bezeichnung"
             styleClass="panelInputField input_mandatory"
             required="true"
             title="Bezeichnung"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trying around, I found the easiest answer to add a "onkeyup" as follows:

```
                    <p:inputText value="#{data.bezeichnung}" id="bezeichnung"
                         styleClass="panelInputField input_mandatory"
                         required="true"
                         onkeyup="$(this).removeClass('ui-state-error');" 
                         title="Bezeichnung"/>
```

If the jquery code needs to be in a more general place, the following might work as well: (it may be helpful to know the escaping codes used here)

```
    onfocus="$('.ui-state-error').removeClass('ui-state-error');"
    onkeyup="$('input[name=&quot;form:bezeichnung&quot;]').removeClass('ui-state-error');"
    onkeyup="$('input[name$=bezeichnung]').removeClass('ui-state-error');"
```